# merge two dataframes based on condition and get id

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have two dataframes:

```
df1

name    year

name_1  2018
name_2  2017
name_3  2021
name_1  2022
.
.
.
```

and:

```
df2

name    start    end    id

name_1  2017     2021   1
name_2  2017     2022   2
name_1  2022     2023   3
```

Now I want to add the id of each name into df1 from df2 based on the following two conditions:

- they have the same name value,
- the year: for example the first row in df1 year is 2018 so if we go to df2, we have two name_1, and 2018 falls in the first row of df2 (2017 <= 2018 < 2021); so we return id `1` in that case

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an outer merge:

```
out = (df1.merge(df2, on='name', how='outer')
          .query('(start <= year) & (year <= end)')
          .astype(df1.dtypes.to_dict() | df2.dtypes.to_dict()))
print(out)

# Output
     name  year  start   end  id
0  name_1  2018   2017  2021   1
4  name_2  2017   2017  2022   2
```